# Can i aggregate a dataframe monthly in Python taking into consideration also the other variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title is not clear enough. The dataset I have is 'df': representing daily data for two 'id' (1 and 2) in the month of january; for each 'id' in each day of january is associated a Value(a or b).  The problem I'm having is that I want, starting from a dataset like df (the links are below), to arrive to df1. So the goal is to group monthly the data but for each 'id' and not the whole values. The Value column should be the sum of all 'a' and 'b' of a certain 'id' in a certain month. 
I don't know if I have been clear explaining the problem. I hope the links below to help you. I am a very beginner in Python and I am facing may difficulties. 
Thank you very much in advance.

[Dataframe df head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mvH6.png)

[Dataframe df end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/werpC.png)

[Dataframe df1: the output I would like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAEwk.png)

Comment: We expect you to post code, not images, so it is easier for us to help you. Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [how to make a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, this should do:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
df1= df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'id']).agg({'value':'sum'}
```

But, as stated, you should post a reproducible example if you want te get better help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I helped! could you mark it as the accepted answer so it doesn't remain open?